# How can I change part of a Django REST Framework JSON response from a list to a dictionary?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

More specifically, I need a nested part of my response to be a multi-item dictionary rather than a list of many single-item dictionaries.

I am returning all the data I want, but I cannot figure out how to format it more sensibly without what I consider to be an extraneous list

Here is the (simplified) response I am currently getting:

```
{
    "uielements": [
        {
            "home-bg": {
                "label_text_color": "#123456",
                "tag_display_text": "young"
            }    
        },
        {
            "home-speak-btn": {
                "label_text_color": "",
                "tag_display_text": null
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like the response to be in this format:

```
{
    "uielements": {
        "home-bg": {
            "label_text_color": "#123456",
            "tag_display_text": "young"
        },   
        "home-speak-btn": {
            "label_text_color": "",
            "tag_display_text": null
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my relevant `serializer.py` code:

```
class UIElementProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UIElement

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        result = super(UIElementProjectSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
        uien = UIElementName.objects.filter(id=result['uielementname'])[0]
        return {uien.name: result}
```

and my relevant `views.py` code:

```
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

...

    @detail_route(methods=['get'])
    def uielements(self, request, pk=None):
        uielements = UIElementFilterSet(params)
        serializer = serializers.UIElementProjectSerializer(uielements, many=True)
        return Response({"uielements": serializer.data})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out what I needed to do is use the code provided by [Dmitry Kovriga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8874621/dmitry-kovriga) not in a new custom ListSerializer, but rather in the view itself after serialization has occurred.

updated **views.py**

```
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    ...

    @detail_route(methods=['get'])
    def uielements(self, request, pk=None):
        uielements = UIElementFilterSet(params)
        serializer = serializers.UIElementProjectSerializer(uielements, many=True)
        result = {}
        for element in serializer.data:
            for key, value in element.items():
                result[key] = value
        return Response({"uielements": result})
```

Comment: If you wanted this to be the rest `list` response you could do `def list...` rather than its own view (which is what I wanted to do).

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom ListSerializer for UIElementProjectSerializer and override it's to_representation method

```
class UIElementProjectListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, data):
        result = {}
        for element in super(UIElementProjectListSerializer, self).to_representation():
            for key, value in element.items():
                result[key] = value
        return result

class UIElementProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = UIElementProjectListSerializer
        ...
```

Comment: thx for this suggestion; it is an interesting approach. However, implementing as you have suggested yields `{ "uielements": ["home-speak-btn", "home-bg"]}` which is missing a lot of data, clearly. The new serializer is returning what appears to be the desired result, but for some reason, that isn't bubbling up to be returned in the actual JSON response. I do not fully understand how the two serializers work together, hence this issue! Any ideas?